# Wordpress Loop - make a new slide with 4 products in

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, woocommerce

I am trying to create a custom product slider using the WP loop and flexslider. I have managed to get a slider with products in, but currently, it only displays 1 per slide, instead of the 4 per slide I would like.

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <?php
      $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',
                                    'post_per_page' => 12              
                   );

      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      $counter = 0;
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; 
      if($counter % 4 == 0) : ?>
        <li>
          <a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
      <?php
        if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID ))
          echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog');
        else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail"/>';
      ?>
      <span class="price">
        <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">
          <?php the_title(); ?>
        </h2>
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"></span>
        <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
        <br />
      </span>
    </a>
  </span>

  <?php
    woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); 

    endif;

    $counter++;

    endwhile; ?>
  </li>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

I'm close, but im sure I'm missing something. I need 4 of the products in each list item..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>One thing I notice straight away is you are opening your li tag inside the "while" closing your li tag outside the "while", it might be as simple as that maybe inspect the html and see is there anything else.</strike>

Ok so here's a simplistic way to solve it you can refactor this to make it a bit tidier but the logic is there:

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;?>

    <?php if($counter % 4 == 0): echo '<li>'; endif; ?>
        <a href="#">WooCommerce Product</a>
    <?php if($counter % 4 == 4): echo '</li>'; endif; ?>

    <?php
    $counter++;
    if($counter === 4) : $counter = 0; endif;

endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: This works, but it appears my idea doesn't. Thanks, though!